# how to see FatalExceptions in logcat when using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, logcat

I've just started work with Koltin and my question might be a little strange to someone who have more experience, 
but how can i see fatalExceptions in logcat? For example, i have an app that is already developed by another dev, 
there is an error in one activity - after pressing the button apps crash and restart to main activity.
I don't see any usefull informations in logcat(in fabric also!), moving on trough whole code from listener to fragment and many classess is very time consuming. There must be some way to figure it out quicker, right?

Comment: if the app crashes and restart by itself, you might need to check the [DEAD] process.

Comment: @hjchin thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions should be shown/thrown in logcat, same as with Java.

If the exception is thown within rxjava or a kotlin coroutine, make sure you have defined an error handler, otherwise the exception might get swallowed.

Then make sure you have selected the right app in logcat and that no filter is active.

Also make sure there is no other global Exception handler defined besides fabric.